# Problems deploying code with Capistrano since upgrading to macOS 10.12 (Sierra), “Permission denied (publickey).”

Tags: macos, ssh, capistrano

So I just upgraded my Mac mini (Late 2012) to macOS 10.12 (Sierra) and everything seems fine, but I’m running into one odd problem deploying code with [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/). I get the following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Never had this problem before in Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) or any version prior to it. Why is this suddenly happening now? Full output of the failed Capistrano deployment below:

```
jakes_mac:SomeCode jake$ cap staging deploy
INFO [hkdgad21] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/somecode/ as jake@example.com
DEBUG [hkdgad21] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/somecode/
jake@example.com's password:
INFO [hkdgad21] Finished in 5.166 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG Uploading /tmp/somecode/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
INFO Uploading /tmp/somecode/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
INFO [xyz20312] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/somecode/git-ssh.sh as jake@example.com
DEBUG [xyz20312] Command: /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/somecode/git-ssh.sh
INFO [xyz20312] Finished in 0.240 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [abcdef01] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:SomeUser/SomeCode.git as jake@example.com
DEBUG [abcdef01] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/somecode/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:SomeUser/SomeCode.git )
DEBUG [abcdef01]    Permission denied (publickey).
DEBUG [abcdef01]    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
DEBUG [abcdef01]
DEBUG [abcdef01]    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
DEBUG [abcdef01]    and the repository exists.
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as jake@example.com: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Tasks: TOP => git:check
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as jake@example.com: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: After trying and retrying the presented solutions, I found out the special problem I was having. Apple ditched DSA in favor of RSA so only this one works now.
The link I found has a step-by-step solution. Good luck! https://medium.freecodecamp.com/upgrading-to-macos-sierra-will-break-your-ssh-keys-and-lock-you-out-of-your-own-servers-f413ac96139a#.345iickdn

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Seems like it’s an issue with SSH keys not being automatically added as it used to be in Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan). Is this expected behavior from macOS Sierra or something connected to OpenSSH?

#### Method 1: Add *all known* keys to the SSH agent.

So one solution I found is to run [`ssh-add`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ssh-add.1.html) with the `-A` option—which adds all known identities to the SSH agent using any passphrases stored in your keychain—like this:

```
ssh-add -A
```

Now this works but it won’t persist across reboots. So if you want to never worry about this again, just open up your user’s `~/.bash_profile` file like this:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

And add this line to the bottom:

```
ssh-add -A 2>/dev/null;
```

Now when you open a new Terminal window, all should be good!

#### Method 2: Add *only SSH keys that are in the keychain* to the agent.

So while the `ssh-add -A` option should work for most basic cases, I ran into an issue recently where I had 6-7 Vagrant boxes (which uses SSH keys/identities for access) setup on a machine on top of the more common `id_rsa.pub` in place.

Long story short, I ended up being locked out of a remote server due to too many failed tries based on SSH keys/identities since the server access was based on a password and SSH keys/identities are SSH keys/identities. So the SSH agent tried *all* of my SSH keys, failed and I couldn’t even get to the password prompt.

The problem is that `ssh-add -A` will just arbitrarily add every single SSH key/identity you have to the agent even if it’s not necessary to do so; such as in the case of Vagrant boxes.

My solution after much testing was as follows.

First, if you have more SSH keys/identities added to your agent than you need—as shown with `ssh-add -l` then purge them all from the agent like so:

```
ssh-add -D
```

With that done, then start the SSH agent as a background process like so:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

Now, it gets weird and I am not too sure why. In some cases you can specifically add the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` key/identity to the agent like so:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Type in your passphrase, hit <kbd>Return</kbd> and you should be good to go.

But in other cases simply running this is enough to get the key/identity added:

```
ssh-add -K
```

If that’s all worked, type in `ssh-add -l` and you should see one lone SSH key/identity listed.

All good? Now open up your `.bash_profile`:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

And add this line to the bottom; comment or remove the `-A` version if you have that in place:

```
ssh-add -K
```

That will allow the SSH key/identity to be reloaded to the SSH agent on each startup/reboot.

---

**UPDATE 1:** Based on [**davidalger**’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39904591/117259) I discovered a nicer, global solution that can work for all user’s on a system. Just open up the global SSH config located here via `sudo`:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

And add this line to the bottom of the file:

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

Did that—after removing the `.bash_profile` fix and all is good as well.

---

#### UPDATE 2: Apple has now added a `UseKeychain` option to the open SSH config options and considers `ssh-add -A` a solution as well.

As of macOS Sierra 10.12.2, Apple (I assume) has added a `UseKeychain` config option for SSH configs. Checking the man page (via `man ssh_config`) shows the following info:

```
UseKeychain
        On macOS, specifies whether the system should search for
        passphrases in the user's keychain when attempting to use a par-
        ticular key. When the passphrase is provided by the user, this
        option also specifies whether the passphrase should be stored
        into the keychain once it has been verified to be correct.  The
        argument must be ``yes'' or ``no''.  The default is ``no''.
```

Which boils down to Apple seeing the solution as either adding `ssh-add -A` to your `.bash_profile` [as explained in this Open Radar ticket](https://openradar.appspot.com/27348363) or adding `UseKeychain` as one of the options in a per user `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: This works, but is it really the only way? If feels so dirty.

Comment: I agree @JakeGould, I just added the `ssh-add` commands to my `.bash_profile` and it works for now.  Hopefully this thread gets updated when there is a better solution.

Comment: @JakeGould / @KevinZych See my answer posted below. There is a new setting in OpenSSH named `AddKeysToAgent`

Comment: For some reason the AddKeysToAgent yes (and reboot) didn't do the trick for me... and neither did the ssh-add -A

Only thing I could get to work was ssh-add -K

Answer (score 8):

> Is this expected behavior from macOS Sierra or something connected to OpenSSH?

This is due to a new feature in OpenSSH 7.2 causing a change in behavior on the part of the SSH client. From the [release notes](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.2):

```
 ssh(1): Add an AddKeysToAgent client option which can be set to
   'yes', 'no', 'ask', or 'confirm', and defaults to 'no'.  When
   enabled, a private key that is used during authentication will be
   added to ssh-agent if it is running (with confirmation enabled if
   set to 'confirm').
```

There were other interesting (security related) features introduced as well, although the release was considered mainly a bug fix release. This particular feature resulted in a default behavior change on OS X since it's default value is 'no' and OS X (I don't know about other clients) previously added keys to the agent as they were used.

So if you add the following to your `~/.ssh/config` file (or the global `ssh_config` that should be located in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`), keys will again be added to your agent as they are used.

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

This one-liner makes it pretty easy:

```
echo "AddKeysToAgent yes" >> ~/.ssh/config
```

After doing this, I was able to achieve the expected behavior:

```
$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
$ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org 
logged in as davidalger.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
$ ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:<snip> (RSA)
```

Comment: It seems that for me, I have to run `ssh -T git@github.com` or I get the same error. Does anyone know why this may be? The adding "AddKeysToAgent" does not help :(

Comment: @ChrisJeon try `ssh -vT git@github.com` to get verbose output and see where it's failing. For me, the relevant line was `Skipping ssh-dss key ~/.ssh/id_dsa - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes`. Ultimately, I switched from a DSA key to a 2048 bit RSA key (`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048`), although you could add something like `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss` to your config file (not tested).

Answer (score 0):

This help me to resolve the issue on MacOS Serra:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s) 
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_file
```