# How to push to bitbucket using intellij

Tags: windows, git, intellij-idea, bitbucket

I have created a project in bitbucket and trying to push code using intellij git. When I created the project bitbucket gave me commands to run within git. Here are the commands I ran and the error I got:

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/[username]/[repo]
git push -u origin master
```

This looks strange because how is this command suppose to authenticate me? Now here is error I got.

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitHub Error Message - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you are creating your project via ssh and for that you need to create and registrate SSH keys.

[Create ssh key](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/add-an-ssh-key-to-an-account-302811853.html)

If you don't want that, create your project only via https

Comment: This shows how to  generate the private and public keys. But how do i register the private key on my system? And tell intellij I have a registered private key?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the ssh key added to your computer?
If you're using oSX El Capitan or newer you'll need to add these every time you restart. [osx ssh keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715135/problems-deploying-code-with-capistrano-since-upgrading-to-macos-10-12-sierra)

How to [add ssh keys](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/add-an-ssh-key-to-an-account-302811853.html)