# How to use Bitbucket as a repository in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, bitbucket, jetbrains-ide

I have tried to add Bitbucket as a repository in IntelliJ ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44620646/how-to-push-to-bitbucket-using-intellij)). However, I came across errors pushing code. I figured out that Bitbucket only allows reading when using access keys.

[image: access keys]

So, I found a plugin that allows IntelliJ to communicate with Bitbucket. But, this plugin has been [discontinued](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/06/discontinuing-ide-connectors-support/?_ga=2.160083581.1527629819.1497829804-1626554616.1494720490). Is there any other way to use Bitbucket with IntelliJ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bitbucket is just Git. IntelliJ supports Git.

You are in the wrong section of Bitbucket. You don't want an "Access key" you want to add an SSH key to your user profile. SSH Keys added to your profile can be used for both reads and writes: `Use SSH to avoid password prompts when you push code to Bitbucket.`

To do this:

1. Click on your user icon in the bottom left corner, and go to "Bitbucket settings".
2. Click on "SSH Keys" tab under the "Security" heading of the settings page.
3. Use the "Add key" button to add your key.

For instructions on how to generate an SSH key, see the BitBucket documentation [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html).